# rbindlist equivalent R's function in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, concatenation

First i am creating empty lists based on length of the num_vars and storing the output of each loop in one list.
After that I want to combine the all the outputs and convert that as pandas data frame.

for this we can simply use rbindlist in R, for combine the list objects.

**for that i used the following python code.**

```
ests_list=[[] for i in range(num_vars)]

for i in list(range(0,num_vars)):
    for j in list(range(1,num_vars+1))
        ests_list[i]=pd.merge(df1,
                              df2,
                              how='left',
                              on=eval('combine%s'%j+'_lvl'))

pd.concat(ests_list)
```

**when i tried the above syntax it throws the following error:**

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only 
pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Please anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your range for i should be from 0 to *num_vars* instead of 1 to *num_vars+1*. The zeroth element of ests_list is still a list.

Comment: No,if i filled that list also it throws me the same error.can you check one more time.

Comment: Please show your adjusted code.

Comment: yes, I updated the above code.Please can you make a conclusion for that.

Comment: Do you really receive the *same* error with adjusted code?

Comment: Your loop over j makes no sense.  Are there any other omissions  modifying the list? Please  initialize ests_lists = list() and use ests_lists.append to add the elements in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for effort , I got  the solution for that,after did some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I found a solution for my problem:*

```
ests_list=[]
for i in list(range(1,num_vars)):
    ests_list.append(df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=eval("combine%s"%i+"_lvl")))
pd.concat(ests_list)
```

I am creating an empty list and and I added each loop output to it.

Then I am combining all the list by using the `pd.concat` function, so it gives me the output in pandas data frame format.